# Add component inside another component ui-view

Tags: angularjs

After my login form I change my view to home page

this is my home.js

```
import HomeComponent from './home.component';
import ListTemplatesComponent from 'listTemplates/listTemplates.component';
import angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';

angular.module('home',[
  uiRouter
])
  .config(($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)=> {
    "ngInject";
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $stateProvider
      .state('listTemplates', {
        url: '/home',
        component: 'listTemplates'
      });

  })
.component('home',HomeComponent)
.component('listTemplates',ListTemplatesComponent);
```

home.html

```
<h3>home</h3>

<h1>MENU</h1>
<div ui-view></div>
```

I want when I show my home page I want to show by default listTemplates

```
import ListTemplatesComponent from './listTemplates.component';
import angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';

angular.module('listTemplates',[
  uiRouter
])
  .config(($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)=> {
    "ngInject";
  })
  .component('listTemplates',ListTemplatesComponent);
```

with this is code its working and I dont have any error

how to have by default listTemplates inside of home when I redirect to home thanks

should I configure this imbrication ,inside of app.js ??

Answer (score 0):

> Try change

```
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
```

> To

```
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location) {

                $location.path('/home');
            });
```

OR

> Use this.

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        component: 'listTemplates'
      });
```